# Need regular expression for pattern this

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for below pattern

1. It can start with / or number
2. It can only contain numbers, no text
3. Numbers can have space in between them.
4. It can contain `/*`, at least 1 number and space or numbers and `/*`

Valid Strings:

```
 3232////33 43/323//
 3232////3343/323//
 /3232////343/323//
```

Invalid Strings:

```
/sas/3232/////dsds/    
/ /34343///// /////
///////////
```

My Problem is, it can have space between numbers like `/3232 323/` but not `/ /`.
How to validate it ?

I have tried so far:

```
(\\d[\\d ]*/+) , (/*\\d[\\d ]*/+) , (/*)(\\d*)(/*)
```

Comment: Tell us what did you try so far?

Comment: So... where exactly can there by slashes? Anywhere as long as there is no space between 2 spaces?

Comment: adding valid, and invaid, examples will make answering your question easier.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
^/*(?:\\d(?: \\d)*/*)+$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/pUOYFwV8SQ

Comment: Ah there was a minor mistake (/+ instead of /*). I just fixed it, see the edited answer and new link.

Comment: One more edit, hopefully this regex will meet all the points.

Comment: @PetrBehenský: Did you get a chance to verify all test cases with my latest regex above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this java regex

```
/*(\\d[\\d ]*(?<=\\d)/+)+
```

It meets all your criteria.

Although you didn't specifically state it, I have assumed that a space may not appear as the first or last character for a number (ie spaces must be *between* numbers)

Comment: Its failing for this pattern ///4443///// which is valid input

Comment: Fixed - see edit (changed start from `/?` to `/*`). Even tested it too :). I think this is the simplest regex that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the last criteria.

```
^(?=.*?\\d)([\\d/]*(?:/ ?(?!/)|\\d ?))+$
```

The best would have been to use conditional regex, but I think Java doesn't support them.

**Explanation:**
Basically, numbers or slashes, followed by one number and a space, or one slash and a space which is not followed by another slash. Repeat that. The space is made optional because I assume there's none at the end of your string.

Comment: Its is allowing ///////  as input ,Its should have atleast one number

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not so simple but it works

```
^(((\d[\d ]*\d)|\d)|/)*((\d[\d ]*\d)|\d)(((\d[\d ]*\d)|\d)|/)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"(?![A-z])(?=.*[0-9].*)(?!.*/ /.*)[0-9/ ]{2,}(?![A-z])"
```

this will match what you want but keep in mind it will also match this

```
/3232///// from /sas/3232/////dsds/
```

this is because part of the invalid string is correct

if you reading line by line then match the ^ $ and if you are reading an entire block of text then search for \r\n around the regex above to match each new line